# Changing the order of pandas/matplotlib line plotting without changing data order

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

Given the following example:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(1,10, size=(8,3)), columns=list('XYZ'))
df.plot(linewidth=10)
```

The order of plotting puts the last column on top:

[image]

How can I make this keep the data & legend order but change the behaviour so that it plots X on top of Y on top of Z?

*(I know I can change the data column order and edit the legend order but I am hoping for a simpler easier method leaving the data as is)*

**UPDATE: final solution used:**

(Thanks to r-beginners) I used the get_lines to modify the z-order of each plot

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(1,10, size=(8,3)), columns=list('XYZ'))
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
df.plot(ax=ax, linewidth=10)
lines = ax.get_lines()
for i, line in enumerate(lines, -len(lines)):
    line.set_zorder(abs(i))
fig
```

In a notebook produces:

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Get the default zorder and sort it in the desired order.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(2021)

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(1,10, size=(8,3)), columns=list('XYZ'))
ax = df.plot(linewidth=10)
l = ax.get_children()
print(l)
l[0].set_zorder(3)
l[1].set_zorder(1)
l[2].set_zorder(2)
```

Before definition

[image]

After defining zorder

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I will just put this answer here because it is a solution to the problem, but probably not the one you are looking for.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# generate data
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(1,10, size=(8,3)), columns=list('XYZ'))

# read columns in reverse order and plot them
# so normally, the legend will be inverted as well, but if we invert it again, you should get what you want
df[df.columns[::-1]].plot(linewidth=10, legend="reverse")
```

Note that in this example, you don't change the order of your data, you just read it differently, so I don't really know if that's what you want.

You can also make it easier on the eyes by creating a corresponding method.

```py
def plot_dataframe(df: pd.DataFrame) -> None:
  df[df.columns[::-1]].plot(linewidth=10, legend="reverse")

# then you just have to call this
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(1,10, size=(8,3)), columns=list('XYZ'))
plot_dataframe(df)
```

Comment: Thanks @spacebrger that's a useful solution but as you said not quite what i was looking for - i didn't know about that legend option either, so thanks for that too!